# Using _s theme, menu changes do not affect header menu

Tags: menus, navigation, customization

I'm using the _s theme and seeing the header menu point to 'Home' and 'Sample page'.

in `functions.php`, we have

```
register_nav_menus( array(
  'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'mytheme' ),
  'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu', 'mytheme' ),
) );
```

Then in `header.php`, we use

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'Primary Menu' ) ); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'Secondary Menu' ) ); ?>
```

etc.

Finally, we have created both menus in the Wordpress custom menu section and added some custom items, but they are not reflected in the site. How do we match them up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be calling the menus by name, not description:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary' ) ); ?>
```